# Function that takes a nested list of strings and returns a new nested list with all strings capitalized?

Tags: python, function, capitalize

This will capitalize them but only if there are no nested lists.

```
t = ['this','that', ['other']]

def capitalize_nested(t):
    res = []
    for s in t:
        res.append(s.capitalize())
    return res

print capitalize_nested(t)
```

I can't figure out how to get it to print out a nested list having all of the strings start with a capital letter. I must be missing something obvious, this just has me stumped.

Comment: Do you need to support arbitrary nested lists (unlimited depth)?

Comment: not at this time, but eventually it may

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a recursive solution (and using list comprehensions also helps make it more compact):

```
def capitalize_nested(t):
    if isinstance(t, list):
        return [capitalize_nested(s) for s in t]
    else:
        return t.capitalize()
```

For example:

```
print capitalize_nested(['this', 'that', ['other']])
# ['This', 'That', ['Other']]
```

Comment: @Amber: good idea, changed (though the question does ask just for nested lists).

Comment: @Amber: Actually I just realized I can't do that at all, because `isinstance("this", collections.Sequence)` (calling on a string) returns True, so it will recurse infinitely on each of the strings.

Comment: True. Perhaps it would be safer to see if the thing in question is *not* a string.

Answer (score 3):

```
def cap(L):
    for i,elem in enumerate(L):
         if isinstance(elem, str):
             L[i] = elem.capitalize()
         elif isinstance(elem, list):
             cap(L[i])
```

Comment: you should not return a non-None value if you modify the list inplace.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: very true. Modified

Comment: The function is not expected to return a value so it is ok to  remove `if:return/else` completely. `for i, elem, in enumerate(L)` will take care of empty lists.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: true. But I was trying to be explicit for OP's sake

Answer (score 2):

Just check if `s` is a list then recursively call your `capitalize_nested` function:

```
t = ['this','that', ['other']]

def capitalize_nested(t):
    res = []
    for s in t:
        if type(s) == list:
            res.append(capitalize_nested(s))
        else:
            res.append(s.capitalize())
    return res

print capitalize_nested(t)
```

Answer (score 1):

The recursive solution is first solution and most beautiful solution, but not always the best solution, Check this iterative solution too:

```
def capitalize(t):
    lists = [t]
    while lists:
        l = lists.pop()
        for i, item in enumerate(l):
            if isinstance(item, list):
                lists.append(item)
            else:
                l[i] = item.capitalize()
```

Comment: You are using `lists` as a stack by appending to it while iterating over it. I'm not sure whether such semantics is guaranteed by Python language but it works on Python 2.x, 3.x, Pypy, Jython. I've used explicit `while stack: lst = stack.pop()` in [the similar solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14024633/4279).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Thank you for your hint, I just improved the code.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version that supports an arbitrary deep nested list:

```
from collections import MutableSequence

def capitalize_inplace(nested_list):
    stack = [nested_list]
    while stack:
        lst = stack.pop()
        for i, item in enumerate(lst):
            if isinstance(item, MutableSequence):
                stack.append(item)
            else:
                lst[i] = item.capitalize()
```

#### Example

```
L = ['this', 'that', ['other'], ['may',['be', ['nested'], 'further']]]
capitalize_inplace(L)
print(L)
# -> ['This', 'That', ['Other'], ['May', ['Be', ['Nested'], 'Further']]]
```